# Is there a shortcut to binary-serialize every property in an object?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary-serialization, iserializable

If there is an object in which **every public property must be serialized** and properties are simple (just numbers or strings or objects already implementing `ISerializable`), is there an easy way to do it without having to create `GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` and a constructor taking `SerializationInfo` as argument every time?

I know that it can be done manually with reflection, but is there a magic method inside the .NET Framework to do it?

---

So the correct answer is:

> Don't try to implement ISerializable - it is for custom serialization. Instead add the [Serializable] attribute right before your class declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the BinaryFormatter class - should do what you need

EDIT: You do not derive from BinaryFormatter - it is a utility class you use to do your serialization. Here is an example copied from the docs

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.n1 = 1;
obj.n2 = 24;
obj.str = "Some String";
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Agreed. Here's a link to the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

Comment: What do I need precisely to do? It seems impossible to derive from `BinaryFormatter`, since it is sealed. Do I have to pass specific argument to `Serialize`/`Deserialize`?

Comment: In my case, if `MyObject` does not implement `ISerializable` interface, it cannot be serialized. If it implements it, the compiler requests to create to create `GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` and a constructor taking `SerializationInfo` as argument. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't try to implement ISerializable - it is for custom serialization. Instead add the [Serializable] attribute right before your class declaration.